# Need N'ko and maybe other fonts for Centos 6.7 to view and edit PDF and binary contents

Tags: pdf, fonts, centos6

I am getting an error when reading a binary in /sbin/ PDF files anywhere to get a font called N'ko.

I searched many places online and used my GUI search tool and did not find any results.

Please help me locate a URL with this font so I can install it.

Also, please let me know any other fonts needed to read these types of files from the Terminal or CLI.

The following is a list of my current fonts:

```
1a61f63f6dd3c0bac6e6737524af16c637b8131e-jomolhari-fonts-0.003-8.1.el6-noarch
250202b87e90a3dae239e372c581385dacd296bd-ctan-cm-lgc-sans-fonts-0.5-17.1.el6-noarch
d7472ff377cbad8c19dd5d88e562ce145ae05770-cjkuni-fonts-common-0.2.20080216.1-36.el6-noarch
02c4e9708abd7a4a272947688881cb24ed579f28-cjkuni-uming-fonts-0.2.20080216.1-36.el6-noarch
a22642b0f3b0e36b32b4f448a34b0187c83b4d8a-ctan-cm-lgc-typewriter-fonts-0.5-17.1.el6-noarch
083611c87fee17bf70562f4a5e22cae454bafde0-ctan-cm-lgc-fonts-common-0.5-17.1.el6-noarch
480bdfabd03ab1a24b995e596da668e3cf2404f2-ctan-cm-lgc-roman-fonts-0.5-17.1.el6-noarch
e2e7b21d2556800774be5347eec044f05c1b4121-smc-fonts-common-04.2-11.el6-noarch
50cf6d280b8b5efb15ab76f5566b7e88715d48bf-sil-padauk-fonts-2.6.1-1.el6-noarch
b0639f3a2a6892ff76440db01aeaeda940708526-smc-meera-fonts-04.2-11.el6-noarch
d5d083fc04f97ac1151957e86ec7f4b9fa5cbdcf-stix-fonts-0.9-13.1.el6-noarch
f174e6cdda7546672001da44a2e30f3fcc18ee72-xorg-x11-fonts-ISO8859-1-100dpi-7.2-11.el6-noarch
87fc988a182637e0db233ad0a33af5d20731dced-xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.2-11.el6-noarch
983c0992e7278550e716fbfcc6cda542e34feef2-xorg-x11-font-utils-7.2-11.el6-x86_64
e707cbd5a9930c060036fc89c067db3dc8d81756-xorg-x11-fonts-misc-7.2-11.el6-noarch
b6f400539062544da9d323e62f78ba8921cb830e-xorg-x11-fonts-100dpi-7.2-11.el6-noarch
d0d38a4960ca7b30d671ee93d04a9d184d47be5d-gnu-free-serif-fonts-20100919-3.el6-noarch
25f79cc4356c0b677dde6b81495393817eb26a2e-gnu-free-sans-fonts-20100919-3.el6-noarch
a87baa70c2c33e48c52a711e28bb72155022f897-ghostscript-fonts-5.50-23.2.el6-noarch
a059fe6beaab6056baf481f0fecf7015aaa517da-google-crosextra-caladea-fonts-1.002-0.3.20130214.el6.1-noarch
3f728e4c3f8463228a3d08cff9e6b6c6d1be5ba6-google-crosextra-carlito-fonts-1.103-0.1.20130920.el6.1-noarch
c6e2eb805a5f00c5767c9d6e33c50bc4328db42b-gnu-free-fonts-common-20100919-3.el6-noarch
8bd0fdea016b7993a427d1ccc4b957e9df2b5e87-liberation-mono-fonts-1.05.1.20090721-5.el6-noarch
44a9a9b994103ca3824bd84efc99ae4e903d2cb9-lohit-gujarati-fonts-2.4.4-4.el6-noarch
ca55f9717f1a8d8df766a91d548a1b970ad02d9b-lohit-bengali-fonts-2.4.3-6.el6-noarch
26f9c4b3433b37df272ec281ea8a7573ae88bf24-liberation-sans-fonts-1.05.1.20090721-5.el6-noarch
55c19776dc11427559938bebd4930818ad646bd9-lohit-punjabi-fonts-2.4.4-2.el6-noarch
fa787df1b84fe4b50ea12fda4b7114c94e136355-lohit-devanagari-fonts-2.4.3-7.el6-noarch
d62c5cd0eabc736d87bc669de1e3fd0eac2dd0fd-lohit-kannada-fonts-2.4.5-6.el6-noarch
f924a95845a7814449f59695cd41696e1dbf7df8-lohit-tamil-fonts-2.4.5-5.el6-noarch
f4a126559c1e3b23b073fd38e58a9c692f604271-libfontenc-1.0.5-2.el6-x86_64
ef306e034658efcb8a0e86f4ee7042d977cf2418-liberation-fonts-common-1.05.1.20090721-5.el6-noarch
c461a25faaf3272e7c288f3b6d1aa7ab0345f725-liberation-serif-fonts-1.05.1.20090721-5.el6-noarch
fd4a03290a91ed7ab7371fbe31ccafa2dbd7c251-lklug-fonts-0.6-4.20090803cvs.el6-noarch
e3c68385d75c8b6c61183fd63dcbd01e1e51432c-lohit-oriya-fonts-2.4.3-6.el6-noarch
f72d6108104fb88ee5c0efa227fba25a59f357f0-libXfont-1.4.5-5.el6_7-x86_64
15bb7f00d4a73d3ad3def2848ac75032051484f2-lohit-telugu-fonts-2.4.5-6.el6-noarch
da6a5e74cd37b0a4c0fc81a4fcbb460c6b8240df-lohit-assamese-fonts-2.4.3-5.el6-noarch
c7cc946c4970730ac96fc1698e617fbfcacd9cda-kurdit-unikurd-web-fonts-20020502-6.el6-noarch
61a68270ec91806e0a848cbd050345f789df170c-khmeros-fonts-common-5.0-9.el6-noarch
e1fe63e74f8f4133db2b08042fdd9142574058a6-khmeros-base-fonts-5.0-9.el6-noarch
1b14d59dfbaa419c8f3c8ebbf40eecc37571a654-fontconfig-devel-2.8.0-5.el6-x86_64
8ddcd1a064d26e97e9a51d898232fc4543d986a5-fontpackages-filesystem-1.41-1.1.el6-noarch
50f5be20479807113830f466211c1304b2af3306-fontconfig-2.8.0-5.el6-x86_64
6040a892621dbc546895a8ff2c3be91a86749992-thai-scalable-fonts-common-0.4.12-2.1.el6-noarch
f2e8d53b2e9234aec858e645ef35ae138c12c04b-thai-scalable-waree-fonts-0.4.12-2.1.el6-noarch
fa6344af32177d7a19c4d0fe08e133b533d9ab60-texlive-texmf-errata-fonts-2007-7.1.el6-noarch
bb6198a6d9d55e0f91f19a835ed8dd6399d619f5-tibetan-machine-uni-fonts-1.901-5.el6-noarch
b5b1bb8d09a48194b064d3d5412a8afc62635e7d-urw-fonts-2.4-10.el6-noarch
09637fec4d2f0d446731b568b0ecc3480779abaa-un-core-dotum-fonts-1.0.2-0.15.080608.el6-noarch
20bb98d0cabca85596da63c3621c741400462575-un-core-fonts-common-1.0.2-0.15.080608.el6-noarch
279150946d58035881830ed5ac20554e9db26969-wqy-zenhei-fonts-0.9.45-3.el6-noarch
4ecb7070809988e2a89a3ce3201efea1ec403b22-vlgothic-fonts-20091202-2.el6-noarch
8938d215aa76e8ed9b75df01d2fbbd61b48371cb-vlgothic-fonts-common-20091202-2.el6-noarch
2d0a75885e65ab1d2c49be2e6cbb81dfe2189afe-dejavu-fonts-common-2.33-1.el6-noarch
dd9c12cb845ef9d8abfb870f602451d20c8ef422-dejavu-sans-fonts-2.33-1.el6-noarch
88a85a6ce1f0f7dee0ef185843ff734efd8a0ed0-dejavu-sans-mono-fonts-2.33-1.el6-noarch
6cbf591866bcf9d651909a701ab243f4bfa6621f-dejavu-serif-fonts-2.33-1.el6-noarch
5ffb229900547dc846c06329013973bf527a3c4e-abyssinica-fonts-1.0-5.1.el6-noarch
5c151ed158d2efd8c9595d1d4022845e1a59d46a-madan-fonts-2.000-3.el6-noarch
f2521d94e4767594281da1efc9d7c39206afae4a-mplayer-fonts-1.1-3.0.rf-noarch
9b821dcad23236e7e8a4c85ccb406a67c58bb2b9-mph-2b-damase-fonts-002.000-3.el6-noarch
59072f74f42da013a4d90e556ca41bb5b70e6311-paktype-tehreer-fonts-2.0-8.el6-noarch
e4c4afc0e04fc5daae049e2d77f75fde9392b73e-paktype-fonts-common-2.0-8.el6-noarch
04acb7c2efaf10bef2eb3abda0ba8b693778c55b-paktype-naqsh-fonts-2.0-8.el6-noarch
```

I have Centos 6.7. 32-bit

Thank you for your help.

Comment: When I am using Terminal on Centos 6.7 and want to read a PDF file, for example, or a binary file, I get a window that opens stating that I need a font called N'ko. The windows offers to search for the font. When I search for the font that way, It cannot find the font. When I looked online for a mirror or file for N'ko, I cannot find one. So, I need help installing the font, N'ko.

Comment: I found a useful article about converting PDF files to text at http://williamjturkel.net/2013/08/24/working-with-pdfs-using-command-line-tools-in-linux/.  This does not exactly answer my question about locating the font my CentOS is asking for, but it does accomplish being able to read PDF files by converting them to text. `yum -y install pdftotext' is the program. The link walks you through the other required programs for this one to work.